# Creating a table valued function that requires several parameters

Tags: t-sql

I need some help with my t-sql code. Background I have a table that BY YEAR data output by columns. So a single row will have CN[Year 0]........CN[Year 10], Premiums[Year 0]......[Year 10] etc etc. I am trying to write a function that takes an integer parameter and then returns a table only for the specified year columns i.e CN, Premium etc etc. Ultimately I'd like to concatenate the tables at some point.I have the basics to run the code manually but unsure how to automate my function so it can return the table.

At the moment I can run the code within 
------from here 
------to here 
manually but not automate the code so it can return  a table

```
CREATE FUNCTION [xxxxxxx_Price_Schema].get_MultiYear(@year varchar(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
------from here 
declare @year varchar(1);
declare @yearNo varchar(1);
declare @customerNo varchar(25);
declare @CN varchar(3);
declare @SQLString NVARCHAR(max);
declare @SQLResult nvarchar(max);

set @year = 1
set @yearNo = cast(@year as varchar(1))
set @customerNo = QUOTENAME(cast('CustomerNumber[Year '+ @yearNo + ']' as varchar(25)))
set @CN = concat('CN',@yearNo)

set @SQLString = 
            '
            select distinct
            [CN[Year '+ @yearNo +']]] AS CN
            ,[Premium[Year '+ @yearNo + ']]] AS Premium
            ,[Age[Year '+ @yearNo + ']]] AS Age
            ,[Sex[Year '+ @yearNo + ']]] AS Sex
            FROM [Test].[Test202002].[PHL_MultiYear_Test_Output] 
              WHERE ' + @customerNo + ' = '''+ @CN + ''' 
             '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
----too here

RETURN @SQLString

END
GO
```

[image]

DESIRED RESULT IF MY input param is 0
[image]

Comment: You can not have Dynamic SQL within a UDF.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti do you have any suggestions for a work around ?

Comment: Please provide a set of sample data (best provided as DDL and DML - read about [mcve]) and the expected output... This might be a case of the [xy-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There might be a better approach...

Comment: If you need dynamic sql, then you would have to migrate into a stored procedure

Comment: @Shnugo data I have is business sensitive so best I can do is as already done describe my table structure and required out.  A mock table will be no more descriptive than stated above.

Comment: @Shnugo. Existing Table has columns [CN Year 0],.......[CN Year 10],[Premium Year 0],.....[Premium Year 10] etc etc. I want to input a variable 0 and return a table that returns only columns for [factor Year 0] etc etc

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I have been moving between stored procedure and function all day. I can now return a varchar from my function  and I can now manually execute that function varchar to give a result. But i want to automate and output a table so I can output multiple tables for multiple params

Comment: Perhaps edit your question with sample data and desired results.  That would help with the visualization.

Comment: @project_kingz Answering your comment above: Oh yes, sample data and expected output was far more descriptive... It should be easy to create a *mock up* with just a few random values...

Comment: *"data I have is business sensitive"* We don't need the actual data you have. We don't even need the actual column names. A simple set of made-up data that illustrates the problem you are facing is all we need. Please read the first three paragraphs of the [T-SQL tag info] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Perfect ! I'll wait for your mockup

Comment: @ZoharPeled is the example provided now enough ? See question

Comment: forgot the link.... https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info

Comment: @project_kingz, I'm confused: *You* are waiting for the *mock up*?

Comment: @Shnugo I had included a sample table and the desired output. I thought you had seen that. I had also included in my question

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Like the look of your example. I'll test now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to get dynamic column names without Dynamic SQL.  However, if you don't mind standardizing the results, consider UNPIVOTing your data

This can easily be incorporated into a Table-Valued Function.

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=86d0fb1c750a2653cd97e2e50e1f5441)**

```
Declare @Year varchar(1) = '0'

Select SelYear = @Year
      ,CN      = max(case when Item like 'CN%'      then Value end)
      ,Premium = max(case when Item like 'Premium%' then Value end)
 From  (
         Select *
          From  (Select * 
                       ,RN=Row_NUmber() over (Order by (Select null)) 
                 From  YourTable 
                 Where 1=1 -->>> Put your actual WHERE here <<<--
                ) src
          Unpivot ( Value for Item in ([CN [Year 0]]],[CN [Year 1]]],[Premium [Year 0]]],[Premium [Year 1]]] )) unp  -->>> Add 2 through 5 <<<--
          Where Item like '%'+@Year+']'
       ) A
 Group By RN
```

**Returns**

```
SelYear CN  Premium
0       0   10
0       0   20
0       0   30
0       0   40
```

**Updated for odd column names [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f3e334feecaa8a2c0fb4d92335fba1b3)**

**EDIT #2 - Variable Datatypes**

```
Select SelYear = @Year
      ,CN      = max(case when Item like 'CN%'      then Value end)
      ,Premium = max(case when Item like 'Premium%' then Value end)
 From  (
     Select *
      From  (Select * 
                   ,RN=Row_NUmber() over (Order by (Select null)) 
         From  YourTable 
         Where 1=1 -->>> Put your actual WHERE here <<<--
        ) src
      Cross Apply (  values ('CN [Year 0]'     ,convert(varchar(50),[CN [Year 0]]]) )
                           ,('CN [Year 1]'     ,convert(varchar(50),[CN [Year 1]]]) )
                           ,('Premium [Year 0]',convert(varchar(50),[Premium [Year 0]]]) )
                           ,('Premium [Year 1]',convert(varchar(50),[Premium [Year 0]]]) )
                  )B(Item,Value)
      Where Item like '%'+@Year+']'
       ) A
 Group By RN
```

Comment: If my columns were in this format [CN [Year 0]] , [CN [Year 1]] etc etc how would you modify your code

Comment: spot on solution. Thank you . Another question - hopefully quick. Some of my columns have data stored in different format so I am getting.---> The type of column "Premium [Year 0]" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list. Any work around

Comment: @project_kingz Different format?  Do you mean different datatype?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant different data type. Some are varchar and others int etc

Comment: @project_kingz  In the future, please supply an appropriate data sample.   Rather than an UNPIVOT. we can unpivot the data via a CROSS APPLY.   Please note that we are converting the columns into a varchar(50) , but you can decide on what is more appropriate.    Here is a dbFiddle which shows the FINAL approach  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=abede0c9f8e2ff20aa19d2859846911f

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I did start to try something with XML and XQuery (what else, chr chr chr). But these strange column names, especially the blanks, were destroying the easy going. Good answer! +1 from my side.